# Regex to get all links to .mp3 files

Tags: php, regex

```
$regex_pattern = "((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|notes|ms-help):((//)|(\\\\))+[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&]*)";
```

This code gets all HTTP links but I only need .mp3 links

Comment: Do you mean "Ends in .mp3" or "Ends in .mp3 if you ignore the query string" or "Resolves to a document with a content-type that indicates it is an mp3"?

Comment: it gets more than just 'all HTTP links' it gets virtually *everything*. I haven't seen gopher in any serious use for *years*.

Comment: @David I was looking to get The Url .mp3 add I m Getting, by putting this in end "\.mp3)"

Comment: @Spudley Ya It Gets All Of Them, I posted The Code in hurry i will use http and ftp only.

Answer (score 4):

Simply put `\.mp3` at the end.

`$regex_pattern = "((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|notes|ms-help):((//)|(\\\\))+[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&]*\.mp3)";`

Comment: Thanks Alot, Can't Vote Up Need More Reputation :P

Comment: @GangsTaRun: You can't vote up, but you can mark this answer as accepted since it's exactly what you wanted - and you even earn reputation by doing that. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need .mp3 links, then you should only need to check for .mp3, so

```
$regex_pattern = "\.mp3";
```